# SQL Server Compact + Entity Framework Design Time Data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-5, design-time

I have an application being designed with SQL CE and Entity Framework. Is there a practical way to make that data available at design time to databound controls in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using an MVVM framework such as Caliburn.Micro, you can set the designer datacontext like [so](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design-Time%20Support&referringTitle=Documentation):

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CaliburnDesignTimeData.ViewModels"
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:YourViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True"
```

There are similar ways to do this using other MVVM frameworks.

Example:

```
public class YourViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public BindableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public YourViewModel
    {
        Employees = new BindableCollection<Employee>();

        if(Execute.InDesignMode)
        {
            // Add an employee when in design mode, this data will show up in design time
            Employees.Add(new Employee 
            {
                Name = "Sample Data Employee"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then bind it in XAML (if the designer datacontext added correctly, the VM's properties will even show up in Intellisense):

```
<Window
    ...
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CaliburnDesignTimeData.ViewModels"
    xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:YourViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True"
    >
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Employes}" />
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

Comment: I usually use Caliburn.Micro for projects, but for this I have yet to add any frameworks. I've noticed that when I bound my data source to the list it created the following in the window resources: <CollectionViewSource x:Key="employeeViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type XMCostAnalysis:Employee}, CreateList=True}"/> adding IsDesignTimeCreatable=True didn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: I believe your binding your data using VS/Blend. Try adding it manually so it doesn't add those markups. I've added examples to my original post.

Comment: Sorry about that, just realized your not using MVVM frameworks. Did you check that the design-time data source has data in it?

Comment: Yeah, I have a SQL CE database with a few records in it. Everything shows up fine when the app runs. I am doing the data binding with visual studio, I'm not sure how to do it manually with a database. The main reason for my requesting this is I have some fields that collapse when certain list boxes are empty. It would be great if I could toggle a design-time connection to the database for that sort of situation.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are you talking about design-time data (some data that shows up in the designer) or showing some fake data while the app is running?

If it's the latter, you can just change the dependency for instance instead of using your actual EmployeeService, you use a fake service which serves up fake data like a FakeEmployeeService.

Comment: Sorry, it is the prior, data that shows up in the designer. I have a ListBox containing 10 Foo selected from a SQL CE database, with a template that shows Foo.Name. When I select the item, a StackPanel appears with a number of populated text boxes like Foo.Name, Foo.Date, Foo.Etc. I was just curious if I could populate the list of Foos from that same database at design time.

Comment: I'm not sure if its possible, as far as I know, you can only show static data in design-time not data from actual services.

Comment: Okay, I suppose I'll just go with the InDesignMode query if I end up needing to show some data in the designer. I'll accept this as the answer until a better method comes along.